# unresolved reference: MAX_VALUE when referencing Number Types with `it`

Tags: kotlin, numbers

`Int.MAX_VALUE` works as expected and returns 2147483647. But when I create a list of number Types, iterate over them with `.forEach` and use `it.MAX_VALUE`, I get `error: unresolved reference: MAX_VALUE`:

```kotlin
val types = listOf(Int, Long, UInt)
types.forEach { println("${it.javaClass.simpleName} ${it.MAX_VALUE}") }
```

So how do I get this expression to work? (And yeah, I'm aware that I could just lookup the [MIN/MAX ranges in the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#numbers).)

And how do I get the type names? Since `it.javaClass.simpleName` produces `IntCompanionObject`, `LongCompanionObject`, `Companion`. But making a list with the different types of Numbers produces names:

```kotlin
listOf(1, 2L, 3UL).map { it.javaClass.simpleName }.toList().let { println(it) }
// [Integer, Long, ULong]
```

Comment: `MAX_VALUE` is a property of the companion object, so you can't reference it via `it`. What do you expect?

Comment: There's always reflection, also you should know that `types` has the type `List<Any>` and `Any` doesn't have a `MAX_VALUE` property

Comment: @Lino The question is _how_ do I then get the `MAX_VALUE` while iterating over the types? In general, how would one access properties of the type if the type was stored in a variable?

Comment: @Lino Ah right, coz it's `Any`, it has no attribute `MAX_VALUE`. So is the only way to access it casting each of those to `Int`, `Long` etc. (probably in a `when`) ?

Comment: Exactly, but reflection would probably be more generic. (You don't have to know the types passed in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get to making this work is to explicitly match each item in the list against a type but that defeats the purpose of making a list and iterating over it:

```kotlin
val types = listOf(Int, Long, UInt)
types.forEach { 
    println(when {
        it === Int -> Int.MAX_VALUE
        it === Long -> Long.MAX_VALUE
        it === UInt -> UInt.MAX_VALUE
        else -> it
    })
}
```

Output:

```
2147483647
9223372036854775807
4294967295
```

Comment: These classes share no type hierarchy, and neither do their companion objects, so there is no way to use polymorphism to get these values. They just happen to have matching names.